# Что делать, если принятый ответ — ошибочный или вредоносный?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, правки, ответы

Иногда встречаю принятый ответ, который в корне ошибочен, либо может нанести вред при его использовании. Самое плохое — этот ответ принят, то есть автор вопроса его действительно использовал. С большой вероятностью его использует и кто-нибудь еще.

## Что делать с такими ответами?

> [**Сразу перейти к ответу.**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/962/181472)
>
> [Определения ошибочного, вредоносного и хрупкого ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1319/181472).

Кроме логичного голоса против, что еще можно сделать? (Понятно, что можно и нужно обратиться в комментарии к автору. Но что, если и автор не отвечает или не согласен?)

- Можно ли сделать правку, добавив в начале «# Ответ неверный, и вот почему:»? Мне кажется, что это довольно грубо по отношению к автору.
- Уместно ли отмечать тревогой типа «ответ необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством»?
- Может быть, вынести обсуждение по этому ответу на Мету? Опять же, не обсуждать же каждый спорный ответ.

## Связанные вопросы на англоязычной Мете

(спасибо @VladD за ссылки):

- [Blatantly wrong accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78438/296059)
- [What should be done with accepted, yet wrong, answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24322/296059)
- [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/296059)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

В любом случае:

- Проголосуйте против ответа. Не жалейте единичку репутации, зачем ещё она нужна?
- Напишите комментарий к ответу, объясняющий вероятную ошибку.
- Напишите комментарий к *вопросу*, предлагая автору вопроса принять другой ответ (или хотя бы пока что снять галочку с ошибочного). Здесь в качестве аргументации лучше всего подходит новый, правильный ответ.

  Такой комментарий со временем получает голоса и становится хорошо виден под вопросом. Этот способ нередко используется, например, когда принятый ответ устарел и поэтому стал ошибочным (но по-прежнему имеет сотню голосов за, и может быть ценен для тех, кто использует старый код или версию ПО).

Далее,

- Если ответ *ошибочный*, и его нельзя легко исправить:

  Напишите рядом хороший ответ, в котором вы объясните, почему выбранный ответ неверен. Он получит свою долю плюсов и с течением времени «выплывет» наверх. К сожалению, промежуток времени, нужный для того, чтобы пробраться наверх, достаточно большой, но он будет короче, если ваш текст будет убедительным.

  Не забудьте проголосовать против неправильного ответа и оставить около него комментарий, чтобы те, кто подумает воспользоваться этим ответом, были настороже! Не стоит повторять всю аргументацию, просто объясните, что ответ неверен, и что в вашем ответе объяснено, почему именно и как надо на самом деле.
- Если ответ имеет существенные ограничения использования, о которых автор не указал (это на грани ошибочности) — отредактируйте ответ, добавив в начале текста предупреждение об ограничениях или побочных эффектах.
- Если ответ *вредоносный*, нужно применять тяжёлую артиллерию. Обратитесь к администраторам (через тревогу) или вынесите вопрос на обсуждение в чате.

  Вредоносные принятые ответы опасны, и (если только вас не переубедят, что ответ хороший) должен быть по меньшей мере снабжён комментарием от модератора.

Comment: Кстати, вот [обсуждение аналогичной проблемы](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/154101) на en.Meta.

Comment: И вот ещё два, практически совпадающие: [_Blatantly wrong accepted answer_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78438/154101), [_What should be done with accepted, yet wrong, answers?_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24322/154101).

Comment: " и с течением времени «выплывет» наверх" - лет через 20.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Ну, если вы лично будете активнее голосовать — то всего через 19.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454 4400 минусов надо. За сколько лет наберется при том, что его другие постоянно плюсуют?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Отличный ответ, там мой плюс.

Comment: @VladD но он неправильный и просто оффтопный.

Comment: А что значит вредоносный? Заведомо вредоносный (типа рекламируется поставить троян) или неправильный и вредоносный (Как я по мануалу добавил ветку sid в репозитории дебилиана, потом наставил софта, возникли конфликты, я выбрал "решить", обновилась libc и я угробил прошивку. Вот за это авторам стоило бы руки снести.)

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Он прекрасный! Любая из фраз (например: _HTML is a language of sufficient complexity that it cannot be parsed by regular expressions._) является полным и полновесным ответом. Ну да ладно, это отдельный разговор.

Comment: Вресоносный — это наподобие «не работает Х — отключите UAC» или там «запустите `echo Y | format C:`, проблемы с заполнением диска уйдут».

Comment: @VladD Именно это и неправильно. Современные регекспы уже начиная с PCRE не конечный автомат. «запустите echo Y | format C:, проблемы с заполнением диска уйдут» - архиватор Бабушкина?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Да, но даже если бы регулярки были полны по Тьюрингу, на них невозможно распарсить HTML точно так же, как и на брейнфаке. Язык регекспов просто не даёт читабельно выразить сложные конструкции.

Comment: "невозможно" и "не даёт читабельно выразить" это разные вещи, вообще-то.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: С практической точки зрения — одно и то же. Неподерживаемый код = отсутствие кода в любой уважающей себя организации.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Расширил ответ, сейчас почитаю обновление вопроса.

Answer (score 10):

## Определения

Для устранения недоразумений даю определения:

> **Ошибочный ответ** — такой, который не решает задачу, поставленную в вопросе. Его *невозможно скорректировать правкой*, придется всё удалить и написать ответ заново.

Пример ошибочного ответа:

- Чтобы распарсить HTML, нужно регулярное выражение следующего вида: ...

Обратите внимание: для тех вопросов, которые можно скорректировать правкой, всё достаточно очевидно — их нужно скорректировать (правкой). Например, этот можно исправить:

- Все символы алфавита языка X описываются регулярным выражением `[Ax-Zxax-zx]`

> **Вредоносный ответ** — такой, который с большой вероятностью может привести к необратимым потерям данных, создает брешь в безопасности, утечку памяти, и т.п.

Это определение расходится с обычным пониманием вредоносного как намеренного. В отношении ответов на SO нам важно не обвинить или разоблачить автора, а предотвратить возможный вред. Чаще всего вредоносный ответ является таким из-за того, что его автор

- недостаточно хорошо разбирается в предметной области,
- неверно понял вопрос
- или скопировал готовое решение из какого-то источника.

Примеры вредоносных ответов:

- «сделайте `git reset --hard; git push -f`, мне это когда-то помогло».
- «не работает Х — отключите UAC»
- «запустите `echo Y | format C:`, проблемы с заполнением диска уйдут».

> **Хрупкое решение** — такое, которое формально правильно, но при небольших изменениях внешних условий может легко стать ошибочным или даже вредоносным. При этом либо условия и ограничения применения не объявлены, либо изменение условий непредсказуемо.

Если ограничения четко объявлены, то это просто решение с ограниченной областью применения,

Примеры:

- Деление на число, которое в рамках задачи не может быть нулём, но в общем случае — вполне.
- Код, опирающийся на неопределенное поведение.