# В чём значение голосов «за» и «против»?

Tags: поддержка, faq, голоса-против, голоса-за, голосование

Подсказки на кнопках для голосования достаточно кратки и не дают полного понимания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема №1:**

Обычно голоса «за» на моем вопросе или ответе не вызывают особых вопросов, а вот «против» — почти всегда требуют уточнения. Не понимаю, что имел в виду голосовавший против.

**Проблема №2:**

Во многих сложных ситуациях этих подсказок недостаточно для того, чтобы принять решение и проголосовать за чужой вопрос или ответ. (Например, вопрос хороший, но задан плохо). Как принимать решение в таких случаях?

Comment: Предлагаю добавить данную публикацию в справочный центр. Что скажите? (У нас уже есть одна [про репутацию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я буду только рад. Но думаю, что для справки его нужно будет переработать. Например, разбить на два, так как здесь совещаются две темы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как вариант: как понять голоса на моем сообщении и как принять решение при голосовании за чужое.

Comment: Как насчет «Что означают результаты голосования и почему необходимо голосовать?».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky почему необходимо голосовать- это отдельный хороший вопрос и он здесь не отвечен.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Суть и смысл минусов в одном предложении:

> Минусы относятся к вопросу или ответу, а не к вам лично. Пожалуйста, воспринимайте их именно так.

## Как понять, почему кто-то проголосовал против моего сообщения?

Голоса — это один из инструментов, с помощью которых сообщество модерирует содержимое сайта. С помощью голосов «за» сообщество отмечает вопросы и ответы как полезные, качественные и понятные. Голоса «против» означают, что данный вопрос или ответ нуждаются в улучшении. Однако, они не расшифровывают конкретных причин, по которым был отдан голос, не сообщают, какое именно улучшение необходимо Это создает почву для непонимания.

#### Голос против на одном сообщении

Можно оставить комментарий к своему сообщению, вроде «пожалуйста, объясните, почему был поставлен минус?». Нередко участник, проголосовавший против, успевает увидеть сообщение и дает ответ.

Прочитайте причины, приведенные ниже. Подходит ли какая-нибудь из них к вашему случаю?

#### Много голосов «против» на одном сообщении

Если голосов «против» очень много, но вы не понимаете их причины:

- Может быть, вопрос отмечен «требующим правки»? Тогда прочитайте сообщение и документы по ссылкам. Когда вы исправите вопрос, его переоткроют и появятся голоса «за».
- Можете задать вопрос в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) или на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Не спрашивайте «Почему много минусов?», лучше спросите «Как мне улучшить мой вопрос/ответ?». Такая формулировка точно лучше, поверьте моему дружескому совету.

#### Много голосов «против», по одному на каждом сообщении

Если на множестве ваших сообщений за короткое время появилось по одному голосу «против» — добро пожаловать в клуб «У меня есть личный ненавистник». Не волнуйтесь, ровно через сутки система вернет вам все голоса и шлепнет ненавистника по рукам. К сожалению, клубных знаков отличия пока что не выдают.

## Что означает голос «за» или «против».

Поскольку голоса «против» определенно требуют уточнения, я добавил *некоторые рекомендации* для случаев, когда вы сами голосуете против вопроса или ответа.

#### О вопросе на основном сайте:

**Голос «за» может означать:**

- Этот вопрос хорошо сформулирован, в нем есть вся необходимая информация. Видно, что автор приложил усилия, чтобы задать качественный вопрос.
- Этот вопрос — о важной теме. Рекомендую всем заинтересованным его прочитать.
- Я просто голосую вслепую, чтобы получить знак [«Электорат»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate). Да, бывает и такое. Но лучше так не делать.

**Голос «против» может означать:**

- Этот вопрос плохо сформулирован, в нем не хватает информации, чтобы дать ответ. Вопрос необходимо дополнить или переформулировать.
  *Если вопрос можно хоть как-то улучшить, например отформатировать код — сделайте это. За правки [даже знаки дают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor)!*
- Похоже, что автор вопроса не приложил усилий к решению и хочет, чтобы за него сделали всю работу.
  *Предложите автору самостоятельно решать проблему и обращаться в случае конкретных затруднений. Отметьте вопрос тревогой.*
- Этот вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта. Считаю, что такие вопросы не стоит здесь задавать.
  *Если можно, предложите автору переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы он соответствовал тематике сайта. Отметьте вопрос тревогой.*

#### Об ответе на основном сайте:

**Голос «за» может означать:**

- Спасибо, ваше решение мне помогло.
- Этот путь решения — верный, он лучше решений в других вопросах.
- Этот ответ содержит важную информацию, рекомендую всем заинтересованным его прочитать.
- Мне нравится портрет автора или стиль его письменной речи.

**Голос «против» может означать:**

- Этот ответ не содержит решения. Это предположение о решении, одинокая ссылка, выражение благодарности или вообще другой вопрос.
  *Кроме голосования, нажмите «тревога» — «не является ответом».*
- Это решение содержит ошибку, которую можно исправить.
  *Оставьте комментарий для автора или предложите правку, исправляющую ошибку (объясните суть ошибки в комментарии к правке).*
- Этот путь решения — в корне неверный или может привести к серьезным проблемам, о которых автор не предупреждает.
  [*Следуйте отдельной инструкции для таких случаев.*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/961/181472)

#### О вопросе или ответе на Мете:

**Голос «за» может означать:**

- Я поддерживаю предложение или идею, изложенную в этом сообщении.
- У меня получилось воспроизвести описанную ошибку.
- Я не читал вопрос, но автор — известный участник StackOverflow. Наверное, он предлагает что-то хорошее.

**Голос «против» может означать:**

- Я против предложения или идеи, изложенной в этом сообщении.
  *В целом, уточнений не требуется. Но если вам не трудно, выскажите аргументы против предложения или предложите более удачную идею в новом ответе.*
- Я не считаю это поведение ошибочным.
  *Аналогично, уточнения обычно не нужны. Но если вы обладаете глубоким пониманием того, почему сайт должен работать именно так, как работает — напишите об этом.*
- У меня не получилось воспроизвести описанную ошибку.
  *Оставьте сообщение: на какой версии ОС и браузера ошибка не воспроизводится. Это может помочь команде разработчиков SE локализовать ошибку*