# А что плохого в этом вопросе?

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-против, голосование

Наткнулся на вопрос, в котором автор обнаруживает непонимание того, как работает рекурсия:

[Как работает рекурсивная функция?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444675/181472)

Оригинальный заголовок вопроса звучал как "Обьясните пожалуйста ,на человеческом языке как работает эта функция".

Ладно, заголовок не очень информативный. Но можно было и поправить. В целом вопрос меня вполне устраивает: он по теме и затрагивает важную тему. Да, автор ее не понимает. Ну и что, минус ему за это?

---

Недавно собирал в один список [возможные значения голосов за и против](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1037/181472). Не стоит ли добавить в документ новый пункт?

> Голос «против» может означать:
>
> - Я забыл, как и когда сам был новичком. Теперь я стал опытным специалистом и ставлю минусы просто за то, что кто-то не понимает
>     элементарных вещей.

Comment: Плохо здесь то что самый быстрый способ вычисления факториалов, факторизация и последующее перемножение методом Шёнхаге-Штрассена как это сделано в Wolfram Mathematica. Там она дает `100.000!` за 11 мс. А наивно-школьный способ из кода ТСа будет секунд 5 пыхтеть.

Comment: @igumnov Ну, допустим, это плохо. Это не значит, что не нельзя объяснить ТСу что делает эта функция, он же не сам её придумал. А в дополнение можно объяснить, что есть более эффективные методы решения этой же задачи.

Comment: На мой взгляд, если *вопрос*  не откровенный бред, то его **минусовать** вообще не стоит. А **плюсовать** надо те *вопросы*, на которые хотелось бы увидеть несколько ответов (т.е. *потенциально неоднозначные* вопросы).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну во–первых, люди просто голосуют так, как хотят. Может быть, немного обидно, когда голосуют против без объяснения, да, но поделать нечего, только стараться улучшить вопрос или ответ, если это возможно.

Я сам не голосовал за или против этого вопроса, так как по–моему выглядит нормально, но я могу понять, почему он может не нравиться людям. Дело не в том (т.е. не должно быть в том), что автор - новичок; это совсем не плохо. Но есть вот такая причина голосовать против:

> Данный вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться

Автор не объяснил, что именно не понимает, что ожидал и почему так ожидал, или зачем ему нужна такая функция.

Я лично считаю, что в этом случае все это можно легко угадать, но представьте, что я задал такой вопрос:

---

### Как работает этот JavaScript код?

```
ﾟωﾟﾉ=/｀ｍ´）ﾉ~┻━┻//*´∇｀*/['_'];o=(ﾟｰﾟ)=_=3;c=(ﾟΘﾟ)=(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟｰﾟ);(ﾟДﾟ)=(ﾟΘﾟ)=(o^_^o)/(o^_^o);(ﾟДﾟ)={ﾟΘﾟ:'_',ﾟωﾟﾉ:((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ],ﾟｰﾟﾉ:(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[o^_^o-(ﾟΘﾟ)],ﾟДﾟﾉ:((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟｰﾟ]};(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟΘﾟ]=((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ)['c']=((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ)];(ﾟДﾟ)['o']=((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟoﾟ)=(ﾟДﾟ)['c']+(ﾟДﾟ)['o']+(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[ﾟｰﾟ]+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ)]+(ﾟДﾟ)['c']+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+(ﾟДﾟ)['o']+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟДﾟ)['_']=(o^_^o)[ﾟoﾟ][ﾟoﾟ];(ﾟεﾟ)=((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+(ﾟДﾟ).ﾟДﾟﾉ+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[o^_^o-ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟｰﾟ)+=(ﾟΘﾟ);(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]='\\';(ﾟДﾟ).ﾟΘﾟﾉ=(ﾟДﾟ+ﾟｰﾟ)[o^_^o-(ﾟΘﾟ)];(oﾟｰﾟo)=(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]='\"';(ﾟДﾟ)['_']((ﾟДﾟ)['_'](ﾟεﾟ+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ])(ﾟΘﾟ))('_');
```

---

Без допольнительных деталей, считаете ли вы, что такие вопросы, которые только спрашивают "как работает этот код", хорошие?

Comment: Это "Hello, world!" сгенерированный функцией [aaencode](http://utf-8.jp/public/aaencode.html).  [Вот здесь есть объяснение](http://cat-in-136.github.io/2010/11/code-reading-aaencoded-javascript-code.html). Много бессмысленного и беспощадного японского юникода.

Comment: Согласен с вами. **Автор должен объяснить, что именно он уже понял, а чего пока что понять не смог, и как он пытался понять то, что не смог.** А то может быть, что он объявление переменных не понимает или что-то столь же базовое.