# Удаление вопроса о настройке интернета на регистраторе видеонаблюдения

Tags: поддержка, модерация, восстановление-сообщений

Прошу помощи в решении вопросов:

1. я против того чтобы у alexander barakin были права модератора. детали в комментариях топика
   [Что означает There is 1 zombie process и что с ним делать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484108/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-there-is-1-zombie-process-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/484113?noredirect=1#comment560732_484113)
2. почему этот топик удален: [«настроить интернет на регистраторе видеонаблюдения dvr, роутер мегафон»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484027/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-dvr-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD)? Это имело прямое отношение к системному администрированию. теперь не докажешь т.к. топик удален.

   а этот остался: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2345/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0
   ? как люди поймут причину и следствие?
3. прошу удалить мой профиль из вашей сети (включая все личные данные) т.к. я не вижу смысла давать советы при таком отношению к делу модераторов (ответы удаляются без объяснений там где требуется помощь а там где нужно дополнение - наваливаются с минусами).

Comment: alexander barakin - не модератор. Он обычный участник. Модераторы обозначены ромбами - вот полный список: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: Удаленные вопросы могут восстановить модераторы

Comment: на всякий случай, исключительно для справки: в моём профиле видно, что я отдал 301 голос «против». львиная доля из них отадана летом-осенью, в основном за вопросы: для скорейшего удаления старых вопросов. последний, 301-й, я отдал, если мне память не изменяет, где-то в декабре прошлого года, скорее всего, ещё до вашей регистрации. я не отдавал ни одного голоса «против» ваших ответов, и отдал один голос «за» ваш [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482459/178576) (я всё ещё «разгребаю» [непринятые ответы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1340/178576), все голоса уходят туда).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin прекратите оправдываться, это бесполезно )

Answer (score 11):

Ох, полегче, пожалуйста.

Давайте я объясню всё по порядку.

- Про alexander barakin и мой вопрос.

  Александр не является модератором, он обычный участник. Один из наиболее опытных в метке [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux). Он вам указал на объективные недочёты ответа — вы предлагаете убивать процессы, которые уже мертвы. А почему вы решили, что он модератор-то?
- Про удаление вопроса о регистраторах: ок, я его восстановил. У этого вопроса есть несколько проблем:

  - Нечетко сформулирован
  - Непонятно, как воспроизвести проблему
  - Признаки вопроса типа «сделайте за меня», в частности *«?!?!очень надо!»*

  Эти проблемы уже обозначал Abyx [в своём ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2347/181472). Если они не мешают вам лично понять вопрос и ответить на него — дайте ответ. При этом, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы мы тоже его поняли.
- По поводу этого:

  > ответы удаляются без объяснений там где требуется помощь

  Где-то мы удалили ответ без объяснений? Если вы о вопросе, то вот, восстановили. Можно отвечать.

  > а там где нужно дополнение - наваливаются с минусами

  Минусы — нормальная часть работы сайта. Ничего личного. Это просто способ обозначить, что, по мнению голосующего против, вопрос является некачественным, а ответ — ошибочным.

  Подробнее об этом: [В чем значение голосов «за» и «против»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1036/181472)
- Про модераторов

  > при таком отношению к делу модераторов

  [Мы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) полностью открыты для вашей критики (и похвалы тоже =) ). Вы можете обратиться к модераторам следующими способами:

  - Оставить отметку тревоги на сообщении, которое хотите обсудить
  - [В общем чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)

  Выше модераторов по полномочиям находится менеджер сообщества Nicolas Chabanovsky. Вы можете отправить сообщение ему с помощью ссылки «[связаться с нами](http://%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)» в нижней части страницы.

Answer (score 8):

1. Тебе все говорят, что ты неправ. Пойми это.
2. Он не модератор. Он проголосовал первым, поэтому стоит комментарий от его имени. И 5 плюсов от других участников, что они согласны.

   > удален пользователем Nicolas Chabanovsky ♦ 8 часов назад

   А вот это модератор - удалил он.

   Вопрос на мете остался, т. к. это мета - она для этого и нужна. Обсуждение тематики сайта для неё тематическое.

Comment: Написал и забыл отправить :(

Comment: еще один всплыл. удаляйте мою учетку, с таким подходом нечего обсуждать.

Comment: @айтишник, это тоже не модератор

Comment: @айтишник: мы вам стараемся спокойно и конструктивно всё объяснить. А вы этот подход ругаете. Если вы не хотите обсуждать — воля ваша.

Answer (score 6):

Уверен, данные ответы полностью раскрывают позицию по заданным вами вопросам. Хочу лишь подчеркнуть, что все действия совершенные Александром пошли во благо сообществу и соответствуют правилам сайта.

Указанный вопрос удалил я, так как он:

1. не относится к тематике сайта,
2. не соответствует стандартам качества,
3. автор вопроса не проявил интереса к исправлению недочетов.

Рано или поздно [система бы удалила вопрос автоматически](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/). На мой взгляд, иногда, лучше удалять вопросы чуть-чуть раньше.