# Вопрос по решению кнопки минус на сайте Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: предложение, статус-так-задумано, модерация, голоса-против

Уважаемые Админы. Добавьте же вы наконец функцию.

Когда человек минусует ответ пользователя. То пускай он напишет коммент. Почему он минусовал.

Тогда Админы и Модераторы смогут понять причину, блочить не блочить. Удалять не удалять. А то зайдут человек 5 кликнут на минус и ты в бане. В начале на час. Потом на неделю и сиди страдай, непонятно из - за чего. Да и самому пользователю будет ясно причина и он в след. раз будет уже умнее.

А то такое ощущение что вы разрабочитки Valve доты. Просто так зарепортили и бан))).

Я в Мету зашел в первый раз, так что не знаю, там ли написал.

P.S. Я как понимаю Meta это Тех поддержка по улучшению сайта? Если не так то перенесите куда надо и ссылку оставтье мне на будущее

Comment: минусы отображают мнение конкретного пользователя к вопросу/ответу, если вы собрали *пачку* минусов, то скорее всего что то в вашем вопросе/ответе не так...

Comment: @Bald, это я  понимаю)). А зачем это все усложинять. Разве нельзя добавить на сайте  коммент. Тобишь нажал на минус. Будь добор напиши почему?.

Просто бывают люди ставят минусы просто так. Такой человек в коммент явно напишет что то типо "фвыафввфыаф".

А коммент поможет понять почему именно минус был поставлен. Вы не понимаете что вы должны бороться с тем чтобы люди не ставили минусы. А чтобы не ставили минусы, Человек должен понять почему ему поставили минус. Ну это же логично.

Comment: я не думаю что кто то целенаправленно занимается *минусаторством* именно ваших постов, Вы вполне можете *поднять* тему на мете, с указанием ссылки на вопрос/ответ, с просьбой объяснить почему *сообщество* так поступило, вполне возможно найдется тот кто сможет Вам помочь. но надо быть готовым что этого может и не произойти, потому что здесь никто этого делать не обязан...

Comment: @xTIGRx а вам не кажется, что даже адекватные минуса будут сопровождаться комментариями типа *"фвыафввфыаф"*? Ибо тратить своё время на описание того, почему ответ/вопрос плохой не каждый может себе позволить. Автор видит минус - он должен сам понять, что он сделал не так. Правила ruSO всё понятно описывает. И без комментариев должно быть понятно, за что минус. :)

Comment: А почему люди не должны ставить минусы? Минусы показывают что вопрос плох и его надо улучшить. Критерии для вопросов описаны в справке [ask]

Comment: @xTIGRx, стоило прочитать и второе предложение комментария :-) к тому же сам говоришь, что _в коммент явно напишет что то типо "фвыафввфыаф"_, а это **никак** не поможет понять почему именно минус был поставлен.

Comment: @xTIGRx  а вы грубый. Общаться с вами мне стало, вдруг, очень неприятно. Всего вам доброго.

Comment: *вангую* минусы в вашем случае могут быть отношением к Вам, ввиду вашей грубости к другим участникам сообщества

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [этот ответ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/).

Answer (score 11):

> Тогда Админы и Модераторы смогут понять причину, блочить не блочить. Удалять не удалять. А то зайдут человек 5 кликнут на минус и ты в бане.

Так работает модерация в сети Stack Exchange. Все участники наделены возможностями модерации соразмерно своей репутации. Администрация и модераторы сайта не смогут их заменить, потому что:

1. Они не могут быть компетентными во всех областях знания.
2. Просто не хватит человеческих ресурсов, чтобы прочитать каждый вопрос.

Если ваш вопрос или ответ получил пять минусов - поверьте, это не случайно. Случайным может быть один минус (как и плюс), но рейтинг -5 это уже закономерность.

> В начале на час. Потом на неделю и сиди страдай, непонятно из - за чего. Да и самому пользователю будет ясно причина и он в след. раз будет уже умнее.

Да, не все голоса против сопровождаются объяснениями. Но как правило под вопросом появляются уточняющие комментарии. Если вопрос закрывается - всегда есть поясняющий комментарий и ссылка на нужную страницу справки. Пожалуйста, читайте справку. Она здесь не для формальностей. Справка писалась и много раз переписывалась в стремлении помочь участникам освоиться на сайте и получить пользу от его использования.

> Когда человек минусует ответ пользователя. То пускай он напишет коммент. Почему он минусовал.

Обсуждалось, но принято не было. Если обязать всех комментировать минусы, то

1. Минусов станет меньше и степень объективности оценок снизится
2. Все начнут использовать шаблонные комментарии, которые не особо добавят смысла.

Многие ответственные участники задают уточняющие вопросы или указывают на недостатки вопроса. Обычно их комментариев бывает достаточно. Конечно, разовый минус может остаться и без комментария, такое тоже бывает. Например, у меня есть ответ с `+36 -1` и мне очень досадно, что единственный критик ничего мне не сказал. Приходится смириться с этим )). А от серийных минусов от одного участника вас защищает система.

> Я как понимаю Meta это Тех поддержка по улучшению сайта?

Да, именно так. Вы задали вопрос в правильном месте. Причина голосов против скорее всего в том, что

1. Участники не хотят обязательно писать комментарий, когда голосуют против
2. Вы довольно-таки грубо общаетесь в комментариях

Ещё о том, что означают "плюсы" и "минусы" и для чего используются:

[В чем значение голосов «за» и «против»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1036/181472)

Comment: Не хочу быть предвзятым, но xTIGRx общается действительно грубо. Я раньше на такие сообщения участников в чате отмахивался, мол я с ним не сталкивался. Но сегодня сам столкнулся с этим, и теперь полностью понимаю пользователей, которые жаловались на него. :(

Answer (score 11):

Сначала по сути вашего предложения. Необходимость комментария к каждому минусу сделает процедуру ещё более неприятной, чем сейчас. Напомню, что минусование ответов уже стоит репы минусующему, поэтому, если кто-то заминусовал ваш ответ, то, скорее всего, он имел достаточно оснований, потому что он пожертвовал своей репой.

Движение происходит наоборот в сторону упрощения минусования, например, за минусование вопросов репа у минусующего больше не снимается. Дело в том, что **минусы очень важны для работы сайта**: они позволяют оценить качество контента.

Ваше предложение сильно уменьшит количество минусующих, что испортит качество оценки контента на сайте, что испортит качество сайта в целом. Поэтому ваше предложение не будет принято.

---

Теперь про вашу проблему. Если вы не знаете, чем заслужили большое количество минусов, то **правильное действие — задать на Мете вопрос**, чтобы вам объяснили, что не так, и помогли исправить пост. Продолжать создавать новые вопросы на основном сайте, не разобравшись с проблемой — неправильно.

Проблема непонимания причины минусов есть только у новичков. У завсегдатаев и уж тем более у модераторов обычно не вызывает проблем понять, чем вызвана такая реакция. Как правильно заметил Ник, один-два минуса могут быть случайными, но пять минусов случайными почти никогда не бывают. Обычно это вызвано непониманием правил.

Comment: Спасибо, что делаете акцент на помощи участнику.

Comment: Что касается минусов: я бы даже повысил их влияние на репутацию. Сейчас один голос за даёт столько же, сколько снимают пять против (или 2,5 в случае вопроса). То есть можно оставаться на плаву, публикуя довольно плохие вопросы и ответы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вот-вот! А то минусуешь, минусуешь, а репа у цели всё растёт и растёт( Достаточно одного левого акка цели минусов, чтобы нивелировать труды пятерых юзеров, заботящихся о качестве контента( [meta-tag:нытьё]

Comment: @NickVolynkin Проблема поднималась, не получилось найти нормального решения: если поднять эффект на репе минусуемого, то разумно поднять эффект на репе минусующего, иначе разрыв будет нечестным; однако даже потеря одного очка слишком многих отпугивает, а уж поднятие до потери двух очков вовсе всех распугает. В результате решили остановиться на текущем решении, когда система раздаёт автобаны, а эффект минусов на репе больше эмоциональный.

Comment: @Discord этот вопрос как раз и вызван работой системы автобанов. Досадно, что автопонимание не встроено в эту систему и какая-то доля участников в итоге не учится.