# Необоснованные минусы вредят развитию Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, голоса-против

Предлагаю, при выставлении минуса какого-либо вопроса/ответа, требовать от выставлявшего негативную оценку, написать объясняющую причину этого минуса, в принудительном порядке. Или же, поставить минус будет нельзя. Также, чтобы любой человек мог ознакомиться с причиной негативной оценки.

Зачем это нужно?

1. Если человек как-нибудь неправильно задал вопрос, и получил за это минус, то после выставлении минуса, он сможет подредактировать или удалить его. Главное то,  что он сможет получить и рассмотреть объяснение/взгляд другого человека,  по поводу негативной оценки этого вопроса/ответа и сделать определённые выводы.
2. Если человек поставил минус, возможно он это сделал ошибочно. При дальнейшей дискуссии с топикстартером/отвечамшим, у него будет возможность понять это и исправить оценку.

---

Вы своим минусом приносите вред как этому вопросу, сообществу stackoverflow, так и человеку который его задал. И этот вред должен быть оправдан тем человеком, кто его причиняет. Другими словами - вы сбили взлетающий самолёт, объясните причину. Может там и вправду находились террористы для совершения второго 11 сентября, а может там были обычные граждане и вам просто показалось что они террористы.

---

Это конечно опасно сразу вводить такую систему на глобальном уровне всего проекта. Я предлагаю провести анализ в определённых, локальных, рамках проекта. И тогда можно будет с чем-то сравнивать. А сразу переходить на такую систему, конечно очень опасно/рисковано. Потому что есть не мало серьёзных причин, сомневаться в успешности новой системы минусования. Но, всё равно, этому проекту придётся развиваться. Поэтому, проведения подобного анализа, будет наверное, правильным решением.

Развивается всё в нашей вселенной, так уж она построена, если проект будет стоять на месте, он будет уничтожен рано или поздно. Для того что бы проект развивался, надо над ним постоянно работать и двигать вперёд. А проведения анализа системы в определённых локальных рамках проекта, было бы наверное очень не плохо для дальнейшего развития этого проекта. Да, может быть минусы и полезны, а может быть и нет. Как показала последняя практика на stackowerflow, необоснованные минусы не полезны, а наоборот вредят развитию проекта.

---

> От Nick Volynkin: коллеги, придержите минусы и закрывашки. В вопросе автор выражает точку зрения, которая раньше (вроде бы) не обсуждалась: *возможность оставлять минусы без комментариев препятствует или тормозит развитие Stack Overflow на русском*. Давайте аргументированно обсудим, рассмотрим примеры.

близкие по теме вопросы:

- [Настаивать на оставлении комментария при голосовании против вопроса с репутацией 0](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4013/178576)
- [Голоса против без каких-либо пояснений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/178576)
- [Вопрос по решению кнопки минус на сайте Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3144/)
- [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/)

---

Comment: Даже затрудняюсь сходу сказать, сколько раз этот вопрос уже поднимался.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin А какая причина почему это до сих пор не принято? И я удалю вопрос тьфу... предложение

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов забавно, но частая реакция авторов ответов на "поясняющий комментарий" - поставить на такой комментарий тревогу "неконструктивный"

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов а еще в некоторых случаях минуса ставит сама система, в ответ на совершенно невинные действия - например, редактирование.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов вы выстраиваете рассуждение следующим образом: проекту придётся развиваться => нужно вводить такую систему в локальных рамках. Я вижу здесь нарушение логики. Существующая система никак не ограничивает развитие Ru.SO и остальных сайтов сети. Наоборот, минусы полезны, в том числе минусы без комментариев.

Comment: `Как показала последняя практика на stackowerflow` – пожалуйста, приведите примеры того, как минусы повредили развитию проекта.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4428/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-stackoverflow-%D0%BD?noredirect=1#comment15188_4428

Comment: @Nick Volynkin  Вот тут и ниже читайте или даже с самого начала - Описываю причину минуса: мне не нравится, когда мне запрещают ставить минусы без указания причины.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов автор не согласен с вашей позицией. Это нормальная причина для минуса на Мете. И вообще, минус на предложение на Мете — это нормальная, штатная ситуация. Объясните пожалуйста, как это вредит развитию проекта?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Я понял что я сделал не так и подредактировал сообщение на более лояльный тон. Потому что он ранее был в повелительном наклонении

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Вы не поняли в чем он именно ен согласен. Что бы поняттьь нужно все все прочить включая то что уже отредактировано

Comment: И как это отвечает на вопрос? В чём именно вред от минусования проявился?

Comment: @Nofate В том что человек будет знать что лучше и как лучше ему делать. И в том что будет более адекватная оценка, более качественные вопросы и ответы

Comment: @Nofate равно = больше аудитории

Comment: @Сорри ребят, мне пора бежать! Удачи!

Comment: @Grundy больше я на мету не приду

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов не обижайтесь на минусы, это всего лишь мнение участников общества к предлагаемой идее, а не лично к Вам.

Answer (score 14):

Мне кажется, такая система *деанонимизирует* минусующего, и тем самым будет провоцировать отвечающего на минусы в отместку. Кроме того, это может стать причиной неконструктивной дискуссии в комментариях («Я не согласен с твоей критикой ответа, а ну убрал свой жалкий минус!»).

С другой стороны, поднятая проблема актуальна, комментарий помогает участнику понять, в чём же проблема с его вопросом или ответом, и, возможно, приведёт к улучшению этого вопроса/ответа. Или хотя бы поможет сторонним читателям понять, где же у этого вопроса/ответа потенциальные проблемы.

Я бы решал проблему по-другому. Мне кажется, нужно *поощрять* комментирование минусов, но не *требовать* его. Хорошо бы создать такую обстановку на сайте, которая способствует (доброжелательной!) критике и культурной, полезной всем участникам дискуссии.

Comment: Отдавать -1, потраченные на минус, при написании комментария?

Comment: @PashaPash: Нет, я имел в виду психологическое поощрение, а не автоматику.

Comment: @PashaPash и прибавлять еще один +1 :)

Comment: @VladD а какое может быть психологическое поощрение в данном случае?

Comment: @Alex: Ну, если многие будут писать «Я поставил минус, и сейчас объясню, почему...», то человек увидит, что тут так принято. И ему будет приятно быть частью потока.

Comment: @VladD это весьма спорное утверждение. на мой взгляд лучше знаков не придумать.

Comment: @Alex: Мне кажется, что должно сработать, теорияразбитыхокон и всё такое. Но я не психолог, конечно.

Comment: Теория разбитых окон работает по принуждению. По моим наблюдениям автор получает минусы когда игнорирует комментаторов либо когда явный и наглый оффтопик. Как-то не хочется всплывающих окон с предложение оставить комментарий к минусу, но возможно стоит попробовать это на деле. Может быть и приживется.

Comment: @Alex: Под разбитыми окнами я имел в виду молчаливые минусы :)

Comment: например, можно требовать комментарий лишь при репутации «минусующего» либо автора «минусуемого» вопроса (ответа) ниже заданной величины.

Comment: Кстати, закрытые вопросы деаномизируют тех, кто их закрыл. Поэтому есть возможность обратиться к ним в чате или на Мете.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky здесь вопрос о минусах, а не о закрытии

Comment: @Alex  Но если закрывающие не боятся показать лицо, то и минусующие могут это пережить.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky: Тогда, возможно, минусующих будет столько же, сколько и закрывающих?

Comment: @VladD `возможно, минусующих будет столько же, сколько и закрывающих` - вообще ни разу не факт.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Ну мне так почему-то кажется, но полную гарантию может дать только страховой^Wвывод психолога.

Comment: Мне кажется, что минусовать легче, чем объясняться и чем задавать уточняющие вопросы. Если публичность отметки заставит немного напрячься, может получиться хорошо. А если принуждать к этому только до определённой репутации, то это просто тренировка на умение давать обратную связь.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Вы не понимаете проблему. одно дело закрыть вопрос(это как крайняя мера, и здесь важно указать причину закрытия). другое дело мнение участников в отношении вопроса(хороший, плохой  и т.п.). И дело не в страхе минусующих показать лицо, а в том, что может появится дополнительная обязанность. А прибавление обязанностей(не путать с добровольным комментарием) влечет снижение качественной оценки. Очень важно не переборщить с мерами. В большинстве под вопросами и так можно наблюдать причину низкой оценки.

Comment: @Alex Возможно, мы с вами про разные аспекты говорим. Давайте воздержимся от оценок друг друга.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky а где Вы увидели оценку Вас или кого-либо? ) Здесь обсуждается проблема и различные мнения и только.

Answer (score 4):

Скажу сразу, что не призываю что-то менять в минусах, потому что не вижу идеальной стратегии, чтобы всем было хорошо. Просто отвечаю на вопрос, как это может сказаться на развитии сайта. Может быть этот пост кого-то вдохновит на ответ, что можно было бы сделать с минусами или просто подбросит пищу для размышлений.

Скажу сразу что имею ввиду минусы **не на Мете**!

## Попытаюсь обсудить причины почему я вижу вред для *любого* сайта сети StackExchange (в том числе и для этого).

Говорю сразу, что описываю своё мироощущение, оно может выражать мировоззрение части людей, но абсолютно точно, что не все так устроены.

#### До StackOverflow

В течение очень долгого времени меня не было на StackOverflow (посещал как анонимус только), потому что я очень стеснялся давать свои ответы и задавать вопросы, потому что боялся что их не воспримут положительно. Во многом из-за функциональности "минусования".
Хотя часто я знал то, что не было в ответе или видел в ответах фактические ошибки.

#### Активный пользователь StackOverflow

Поэтому мой когда первый вопрос "плюсанули" после одного минуса, я был просто счастлив. Затем когда я давал ответы и задавал вопросы, которые плюсовались, меня всё больше и больше это радовало и убирало мою боязнь что-то спрашивать или отвечать.

Но я уверен, что я бы мог в какой-то момент плюнуть и уйти, если бы отхватил пачку минусов в критическое время "первых шагов". Полагаю, что то же самое справедливо и для новичков, которыми нередко щедро и густо задаривают "минусами".

#### Текущее время

Сейчас минусы для меня слабо что-то меняют, но точно *не помогают* лично для моих ответов. Самый "конструктив" — это комментарий, в чём именно "косяк" моего ответа, что я не учёл и т.д. От минусов лишь остаётся неприятный осадок и ни разу не было так (на данный момент), когда минус вдохновил меня что-то поменять в своём ответе, так как я и так стараюсь отвечать максимально уважительно и подробно. Поэтому и не остаётся другого варианта кроме как воспринимать минусы как чью-то неадекватность.

#### Что же делать с минусами?

Не могу сказать однозначно что же с ними делать. Не вижу стратегии "чтобы всем было хорошо". Я лично был бы не против неанонимности и плюсов, и минусов. И обязательного комментария и т.д. Но у этого могут быть свои нежелательные последствия.

Comment: Просто бывают новички (и не только новички) задающие совершенно неадекватные вопросы, не ознакомившись с правилами сайта. Например в духе "эй, холопы, написали мне код быстро-быстро". Вот что с такими делать еще?

Comment: А минус на мете - совершенно отдельная история. Так как он не влияет на репутацию, это скорее что-то в духе "согласен-не согласен" с предложением

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Согласен по поводу вопросов-домашек, но часто отхватывают минуса прос.то новички за то, что просто новички. Иногда они не умеют формулировать внятно вопрос (для этого можно его просто попросить комментариев или просто закрыть), или просто за то, что новичок.

Comment: Вот не поймет вас Алексей Шиманский и меня не поймет, когда я плюсую новичков до 200 репутации за пусть и плохие вопросы, но где постарались форматирование сделать или исправляли вопрос после комментариев к вопросу. Знаете, как преподаватели смотрят на студентов, которые не знают ответа, но после легкой подсказки выплывают, либо после более явной нащупывают почву. Но новичков много разных, вот утка о других пишет - поэтому кажется, что у нас у всех такие якобы противоречия. Приеду с вокала напишу подробнее.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму К сожаленью толерантности некоторым участникам не хватает и некоторые товарищи не брезгуют грубить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, отмена минусов не помешает им грубить в комментариях, увы.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Да про минус на мете я в курсе, я его тут не рассматриваю.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov а новичков проявляющих признаки адекватности большинство пользователей итак особо не минусуют, даже если вопрос по форме-содержанию - не оч.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Далеко не всегда, к сожаленью. И закрывают тоже бывает нормальные вопросы как "не по теме".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, в общем есть и еще одно положительное свойство минусов, которое Вы не упомянули. Есть некоторое количество весьма странных пользователей, которые имеют некоторое значимое число репутации, при этом большинство ответов - вопросов в лютом минусе. Потому что минус весит на самом деле очень мало в числах. Убери или ограничь минусы - репутационная система, итак критикуемая (жалко Dmitriy Simushev не пинганется отсюда), полетит совсем.

Comment: То есть минусы - они итак очень слабы, куда их дальше резать?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Ответил в обновлении ответа (забавная тавтология).

Comment: `воспринимать минусы как чью-то неадекватность` ....... какой-то бред....Какое-то странное утверждение...получается, что все вопросы/ответы являются абсолютно адекватными, а вот все, кто минусует, наоборот — самые неадекватные люди на ресурсе? Вы серьезно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это вы так додумали и воприняли моё утверждение. Если я не вижу куда можно улучшить мой ответ и человек не поясняет своего недовольства, то как мне стоит вопринимать его "минус"?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov эта тема **обсасывалась** (как говорит Утка)  тысячу раз... Самое простое: 1 минус — ничего не значит и можно не обращать внимание, 2 — тоже бывает, но все же стоит заглянуть в справку, 3 и более — явно что-то не то. Вам так не кажется?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Понимаю, я один минус максимум получал, но всё равно было неприятно. Даже если у меня ещё 10 плюсов есть. Поэтому я скорее за этот случай говорю.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если это всё принимать так близко к сердцу, то можно не дожить до следующего года))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я знаю, поэтому уже не так парюсь:-)