# Возможность понижения рейтинга вопроса только при наличии комментария объясняющего причину или "тревоги"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

*Это глобальное предложение для всего SO в принципе, если необходимо я могу продублировать предложение в англоязычной версии.*

И так. Лично для меня SO это последняя линия "обороны". Если с проблемой не помогли ни Google, ни даже существующие ответы на SO. Только тогда, я собственно задаю вопрос. В связи с этим (лично мне) отрицательный рейтинг хотя бы даже на одном моем вопросе кажется чем то невероятным. Поймите правильно, *сам рейтинг меня слабо волнует*. Но если его понизили, значит либо вопрос был на столько глупым или не правильным. И я более чем уверен что задать глупый вопрос может кто угодно. И это совсем не страшно. Но...

#### Проблема

Когда рейтинг понижают без объяснения причины, например от обиды что ответ не приняли как лучший или по каким то еще, не особо веским причинам. Это очень не хорошо. Ведь вопросы с отрицательным рейтингом удаляются автоматически через какое то время. Соответственно даже если кто от ответил правильно или (еще более тяжелая ситуация) я сам нашел ответ и опубликовал его. То вопрос скорее всего будет удален. А если я сам ответил на него, то я даже не могу увести рейтинг в 0.

#### Логичное решение

Даунвойт - законное право пользователей SO. И почти всегда он оправдан. Собственно этим оправданием может быть "тревога" или комментарий с причиной понижения рейтинга. Я считаю что это верно. Объективная причина, поможет либо исправить вопрос, либо и вовсе его удалить. По этому считаю что описание причины понижения рейтинга должно быть не предложением, а условием. К тому же при отправке тревоги, можно поставить чекбокс, понизить рейтинг.

### UPD 1 ##

Хотелось бы уточнить что речь в предложении идет только о **самом вопросе**.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Насколько я могу видеть у вас 2 вопроса и оба никто ни разу не минусовал. (или я ошибаюсь и смотрю куда-то не туда?)

Comment: Во первых речь о проблеме вообщем. Во вторых, есть ведь еще и SO.com аккаунт. Вот вам например, не было бы удобнее, если бы вы знали причину по которой ваш вопрос считают плохим?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Голоса против без каких-либо пояснений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277/%d0%93%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: и еще дубликат [Вопрос по решению кнопки минус на сайте Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3144/191482), [Необоснованные минусы вредят развитию Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4452/191482) и где-то еще 3 дубликата

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, моя ошибка. Это именно дубликат. Однако за 3 года вообщем никаких изменений.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin о каких изменениях вы говорите? Комментарии не будут обязательными при минусовании. Это было написано во всех ответах. Что-то разве не так?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, 202 голоса за идею и 45 отслеживают. И это вопрос на мете. Если это на столько обширная дискуссия то да, определенно что то не так) В любом случае, вопросик удалю и подйду голосовать за идею на Английском SO.

Comment: Не надо удалять.

Comment: И плюсы тогда обосновывать комментарием! А то кто-то постоянно плюсует что попало.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev хуже того, зеленую галочку лепят на неправильные ответы!

Comment: @Qwertiy, если вопрос уже поднимался, какой смысл его оставлять?
P. S. На эмоциях поднял вопрос не убедившись что нет дубликатов.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, чтоб лучше искался по разным формулировкам.