# За что меня минусуют

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-против

Привет. Вчера ответил человеку на вопрос. Старался дать максимально развёрнутый ответ. Но, в итоге, наполучал за что-то минусов. За что!? О_о

[Ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645227/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8/646247#646247).

Comment: У вас всего один минус. Вероятно кому-то что-то не понравилось. В данном виде мне мог бы не понравиться совет хранить все простые до 18446744073709551557

Comment: Но скорее всего этот минус относится к первой редакции вашего ответа.

Comment: вопросы являющиеся дубликатами следует сразу закрывать как дубликат, без сожалений, без эмоций

Comment: Было 2 минуса. Меня это задело. Что касается Вашего комметария, то здесь Вы неправы. Разбираться в P-1 методе Полларда -- это затратно. При этом, в качестве неплохой скорости и наличии 1ГБ памяти вполне себе можно использовать предподсчёт простых чисел. Разумеется, коль скоро мы хотим получать их в большом количестве, моё решение не подойдёт. Но, следует заметить, что все решения в той или иной степени имеют ограничения.

Comment: @hedgehogues что бы пришла нотификация не забывайте указывать символ `@`перед ником в теле комментария. мне кажется следует добавить в явном виде в ответ упоминание по поводу *затратности* хранения предрасчитанных простых чисел

Comment: @Bald, хорошо, поправлю. Что касается @, то что делать, если ник состоит из двух слов?

Comment: когда Вы ставите символ `@` и начинаете набирать ник пользователя *система* Вам предлагает выбор участника к кому Вы можете обратиться, и Вы можете выбрать его

Comment: @Bald, такое происходит не всегда. Я с этим уже не однократно сталкивался. Когда-то система предлагает поставить ник, когда-то -- нет.

Comment: @hedge можно не весь ник, всё равно уведомление будет.

Comment: у меня у вопроса с +18  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/603544/191482  стоит минус, но я не грущу))) у ответов у некоторых тоже бывает.... никогда не угадаешь за что минус. Если их не пачка, а, например, только один, то обращать внимание, наверное, не стоит.

Comment: Было два. Вот мне и взгрустнулось. Сейчас -- всё ок.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку

Comment: _Что касается @, то что делать, если ник состоит из двух слов?_ пробелы убираются

Comment: Второй минус был мой. Я убрал его после выпиливания первого абзаца, как и комментарии по этому поводу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один минус != "наполучал за что-то минусов". Разовые минусы, да и плюсы тоже, — вещь довольно случайная и субъективная. Их получают абсолютно все. И даже на самых лучших ответах, в которые вложены часы работы, бывают минусы.

Сохраняйте спокойствие и продолжайте работу. Плюсы придут.

- [Голоса против без каких-либо пояснений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/181472)
- [В чем значение голосов «за» и «против»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1036/181472)