# Всем чмоке в этой истории правок

Tags: обсуждение, предлагаемые-правки

Обнаружил тайный заговор подпольной группы граммар-нацистов. Они обмениваются сообщениями в описаниях к предлагаемым правкам. Смотрите сами, что пишут:

> - Ужасная грамматика, не те метки
> - исправьте же орфографию, наконец! у вас всех шоры на глазах, что ли?
> - ставьте дефис как следует!
> - в школе нужно было учиться хотя бы русскому языку
> - фывфывфывфыв

Последнее, похоже, шифровка.

Вот [ссылка, чтобы почитать самостоятельно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits?filter=month&tab=All) для [тех, кто допущен к гостайне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Я осилил только август, впрочем самое интересное там за последние пару дней.

Нужно ли что-то с этим делать? Что?

Comment: Хех! Хорошо подмечено! Я, кстати, тоже грешен — в какой-то правке оставил (невидимый) `<!-- html-комментарий -->`.

Comment: @VladD: можно так маскировать настоящий ответ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

А что с этим можно сделать?

Комментарий это лишь дополнение, расшифровывающее детали исправления. В 90% случаев он просто не нужен - из правки и так всё ясно. В 10% случаев - да, бывает нужно уточнить, что правка сделана из тех-то соображений (например исправляет опечатку в синтаксисе кода отвечающего)

- Если правка хорошая - принять не смотря на комментарий.
- Если правка плохая - отклонить.
- Если комментарий оскорбительный - сделать правку с хорошим комментарием.

Answer (score 6):

В общем, я тут вижу две проблемы.

Первая — назидательно-хамский тон, который вообще никак и нигде не допускается на StackOverflow. Об этом уже написано [два](/help/be-friendly) [раздела](/help/be-nice) справки.

Вторая — описание правки используется как чат. Так вот,

> ## Описание правки — это журнал изменений, а не стенограмма судебного заседания

Не знаю, как еще больше выделить.

Писать там сообщение для автора исходного текста — бессмысленное занятие. В описании должно быть точно то же, что обычно пишут в сообщении коммита в какой-нибудь системе контроля версий.

Представьте, что вы — тимлид. Вы видите коммит вашего сотрудника с сообщением «фывфывфыв» (или еще похуже). Что будет сотруднику?

Обычно хватает шаблонного текста вроде «исправил форматирование и орфографию». **Редкий случай, когда действительно нужно писать об ошибках автора — это когда вы исправляете ошибку в коде *ответа*** ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25284)). Тогда нужно оставить ссылку или объяснение для проверяющих. А еще может пригодиться специальная [инструкция по работе с ошибочными ответами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/961/181472).

Answer (score 3):

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/428992/6) ситуация вдвойне печальная от того, что участник не только позволяет себе излишне резкие высказывания, но и демонстрирует существенную разницу между предъявляемыми к другим требованиями и собственными способностями. 
То есть, несмотря на столь категоричные возмущения чужой безграмотностью, в собственных правках пропускает множество ошибок, в результате чего эти правки требуют повторной правки.

Что же с этим делать?

Я считаю, что данный случай скорее клинический. Внесенные именно этим участником правки можно отменить, без каких то особых потерь для сообщества и начисленные за такую "работу" скромные 2 балла тут никак не заслужены.

Для профилактики можно  (и нужно) провести разъяснительную беседу о правилах поведения в данном сообществе (например пригласить в это обсуждение), если человек сколько-то адекватный, то он прислушается и, возможно, будет более сдержан в своих высказываниях.

А вообще по вопросу согласен во всем [с этим ответом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1174/177345)

Comment: Я собрал формулировки от троих разных участников, если что )

Comment: @NickVolynkin точно, сослаться забыл ..

Comment: не удержался, тоже там внес правку )