# Нужны ли описания для правок, которые не будут проходить проверку?

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Давно получил привилегию делать правки без проверки. И примерно в тот же день перестал писать к этим правкам комментарии, раскрывающие суть правки.

Абсолютно согласен, что в случае проверяемой правки комментарий нужен. Далеко не всегда проверяющий компетентен в теме вопроса и ему нужна подсказка, чтобы понять суть изменений.

В случае непроверяемой правки заинтересоваться изменениями может автор сообщения и, возможно, какой-нибудь случайный читатель. А может и просто посмотреть на diff и понять. Возможно, если правка будет объяснена, то читатель чему-то научится и будет оформлять новые сообщения лучше.

Существенный аргумент против — затраты времени. Можно делать очень много правок, если вы, например, переставляете метки на вопросах или если подправили форматирование кода. Каждый раз объяснять, почему конкретная метка нужна или не нужна на вопросе — это долго.

Пожалуйста, порекомендуйте: стоит ли мне (и всем с этой привилегией) что-то добавлять в описание правки? В каких случаях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема описаний правок в том, что их *никто* не увидит. Если вы хотите оставить поясняющий комментарий, то **отправьте обычный комментарий**.

Описания правок нормально используются только в одном случае: при проверке правок. В остальных случаях они абсолютно бесполезны. Если движок сайта станет уделять больше внимания вручную написанным комментариям в правках, например, добавлять их в уведомления, то я могу подумать над изменением своего отношения, а пока же мне лень тратить время на текст, который никто не читает.

Меньше уважения к комментариям только в ручных объяснениях отменённых правок — эти вообще чёрта с два достанешь, даже если хочешь.

Comment: Спасибо, отличная идея.

Answer (score 1):

Правки меток - явно нет. При достаточной репутации они вообще правятся в inline-режиме без возможности указать описание. Да и в проверяемом варианте я писал просто что-то типа "Исправлены метки". Исправления меток весьма очевидны, а описывать, почему конкретная метка нужна или не нужна кажется как-то странно. Тем более, для формата короткой записи описания правки.

Всякие очевидные правки, типа орфографии, оформления и т. д. в большинстве случаев тоже очевидны, поэтому не требуют комментариев. Хотя иногда напрашиваются на [Всем чмоке в этой истории правок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1159/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA).

А вот исправления в коде или в логике ответа надо пояснять обязательно.