# Следует ли удалять неправильные ответы (в очереди проверок), которые являются честной попыткой ответить на вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок

В очередной раз встретил в [очереди проверок сообщений низкого качества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) ответ, который явно неверен, но при этом не подпадает ни под одно правило об удалении.

То есть я не могу с чистой совестью нажать кнопку "Выглядит нормально", а "Рекомендовать удаление" не подходит -- я хочу просто проголосовать против (замечание: интерфейс *не позволяет* голосовать).

Возможное решение: переименовать кнопку: "Выглядит нормально" -> "Не удалять". Как ещё можно эту проблему решить/обойти?

Существует аналогичный вопрос на Meta.SE без удовлетворительного ответа: [Should we encourage deleting answers that are earnest attempts at an explanation but that are technically incorrect (in the low quality queue)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263755/137096)

Comment: Вы _можете_ проголосовать против — под ответом есть (полупрозрачная) ссылка на вопрос.

Comment: @VladD: интерфейс не позволяет проголосовать, не уходя с текущей страницы. См. мой первый комментарий к ответу alexander barakin.

Comment: Можно открыть вопрос в новом окне :) (как вы и пишете)

Answer (score 7):

если ответ неправильный, значит, он вряд ли сможет быть полезен тем, кто, в поисках ответа на *свой* вопрос, будут читать этот ответ.

с другой стороны, даже в неправильном ответе на *данный* вопрос может содержаться полезная информация для ищущих ответа на *похожий* вопрос.

исходя из этих двух соображений, логичнее всего, как мне кажется, будет проголосовать **против** такого ответа: пусть остаётся, но с «минусами».

Comment: интерфейс в этом месте *не позволяет голосовать* (я могу конечно открыть вопрос в отдельном окне, найти ответ, проголосовать, вернуться в очередь проверок и нажать "Пропустить" -- но это не идеально)

Comment: вероятно, те, кто придумывал (и вносил впоследствии модификации в) эту очередь и её интерфейс, предпочли направлять усилия проверяющих на внесение правки и удаление.

Comment: Отсутствие стрелок голосования понятно, так как модератор может не являться экспертом по конкретной тематике вопроса  (это как правило не нужно и даже мешает для задач модерации). Не эксперт, нажал бы клавишу "Выглядит нормально" для случая, обсуждаемого в моем вопросе)

Comment: @jfs однако в проверке новых сообщений стрелки голосования есть. Там проверяющий участник тоже может не являться экспертом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: очевидно, что некоторые задачи могут требовать экспертизы, например, что является вопросом-дубликатом, а что не является. В данном вопросе обсуждается [проверка cообщений низкого качества](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)

Answer (score 2):

> **Ошибочный ответ** — такой, который не решает задачу, поставленную в вопросе. Его невозможно скорректировать правкой, придется всё удалить и написать ответ заново.

Неважно, как вы нашли ошибочный ответ: через очереди проверок, через поиск или как угодно ещё. Если вы точно знаете, что ответ ошибочный, следуйте той же самой инструкции, что и для принятых ошибочных ответов:

[Что делать, если принятый ответ — ошибочный или вредоносный?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/961/)

Думаю, имеет смысл включить кнопки для голосования в этой очереди проверок. Если проверяющий не является экспертом по теме вопроса, он может не голосовать.

Для добавления кнопок  наверняка лучше всего писать feature-request на Мету SE.

Comment: мой вопрос явно говорит, что я хочу проголосовать, но интерфейс не позволяет (сейчас я могу только кнопку "пропустить" нажать, а все остальные действия в отдельном окне выполнять—что не является трагедией, но можно улучшить, например, как я предложил: переименовать кнопку). Замечание про "не жалейте единичку репутации" здесь не уместно.

Comment: @jfs ваш вопрос о том, следует ли удалять (судя по заголовку).

Comment: Про репутацию- это же просто скопировано из другого ответа.

Comment: *Ошибочный ответ — такой, который не решает задачу* — мне кажется, не *всё так однозначно™*. например: 1. задача вообще не имеет решения. 2. в вопросе содержится несколько под-задач, а ответ относится лишь к части из них. 3. ответ освещает какой-нибудь важный момент в решении задачи (например, дополняя другие ответы), но не является **полным** решением. 4. и т.п.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin пожалуй, вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

А почему их надо удалять? Это попытка дать ответ, не намеренно неверный ответ же.

Такой ответ как минимум может подтолкнуть топик стартера к решению проблемы.

Ну и плюс, если ответ не подходит, то автор вопроса просто не заапрувит ответ. Конечное решение всегда за автором вопроса.