# Слишком быстро принимают ответы

Tags: обсуждение, принятые-ответы

Одна из многих неправильных вещей, которые делают наши модераторы, привела к тому, что в 95% переходах из email-рассылки оказывается, что на вопрос уже дан один (и только один) ответ, содержащий ошибки, но он уже принят, а потому последующие ответы не получат столько внимания, как первый. Спасибо модераторам за то, что старательно месяцами прививали пользователям эту больную привычку "отмечать галочкой ответ не лучший, а первый" своим регулярным надоедливым комментарием "если на ваш вопрос дан исчерпывающий ответ..."

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/961/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9

Comment: 1. Даже если ответ не принят, то первый ответ всё равно получает больше внимания, особенно если второй отправлен на следующий день. Если хотите внимания, пользуйтесь не e-mail, а RSS/Atom. 2. Галочку всегда можно переставить.

Comment: Что-то не припомню чтобы я (как модератор) оставлял подобные комментарии и подталкивал пользователя побыстрее поставить зеленую галку. Модераторам и так хватает чем заняться :) Комментарий "если на ваш вопрос дан исчерпывающий ответ..." иногда оставляет Community Manager, [Nicolas Chabanovsky](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) - и это его личная инициатива.

Comment: @PashaPash ради справедливости стоит заметить что данный комментарий появляется далеко не так сразу как описывает ТС

Comment: Минус шесть просто за то, что дубликат? Прекрасно отображает качество этого комьюнити.

Comment: осмелюсь предположить что минус 6 за [tag:нытье] в данном вопросе IMHO

Comment: Тут тебе не хабр срач разводить. Это не "нытье", а вопрос из жанра meta.

Comment: я написал почему я поставил минус. ничего личного это мое отношение к данному вопросу

Comment: Мне не нравится слово "нытье". Если применять его везде, где кто-то чем-то не доволен, то это далеко не то комьюнити, в котором кому-либо стоит проводить время.

Comment: @Nakilon, [meta-tag:нытье] - это местная чтимая традиция.

Comment: Тэга "whining" на meta.stackoverflow.com нет и, скорее всего, не было. Что еще раз прекрасно отображает качество этого комьюнити.

Comment: Как верно заметил @Nofate [tag:нытье] не более чем *фишка* данного сообщества. если я не вольно Вас обидел, прошу прощения. а если по существу что бы данный пост не выглядел голословным то было бы неплохо привести ссылки

Comment: @Nakilon, у нас не стопроцентная калька большого SO. Комьюнити переехало сюда уже в зрелом возрасте со своим багажом. Он может вам нравиться или нет - дело ваше.

Comment: **Голосую за переоткрытие.** На мой взгляд, вопрос не о том, что галочка попадает на неверные ответы, а о том, что **якобы** дополнительные напоминания участников об этой галочке способствуют  этому явлению.

Comment: @Nakilon на англоязычной мете есть свои традиции и мемы, тысячи их! [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)

Comment: Ну вы сравнили мем, скажем, "Jon Skeet" с тем, чтобы называть пользователей нытиками. Я бы не копировал норму поведения на луркморе, фишкинете и прочем убогом рунете сюда. Но если большинство так комфортней, то это *прекрасно отображает...*

Comment: @Nakilon, в вашем вопросе до сих пор не содержится ни вопроса, ни предложения. Только благодарность неким модераторам.

Comment: Мне казалось, очевидно, что я спрашиваю: "зачем так делать?", и предлагаю: "не делайте так".

Answer (score 9):

*Галочка* не означает что ответ, как Вы выразились *лучший*, она обозначает только то что ответ помог больше других. @PavelMayorov уже привел Вам ссылку в которой расписано что делать в случаях когда Вы не согласны с ответом (не важно, принят он или нет), я в подобных случаях поступаю так:

1. Оставляю комментарий к ответу, где говорю с чем я не согласен.
2. Выжидаю какое то время на предмет реакции от автора ответа, ведь вполне возможно что ошибка допущена не специально и автор ответа её исправит.
3. Если *адекватной* реакции от автора ответа нет, то тогда в дело идет минус, если позволяет компетенция то публикация другого ответа, возможно привлечение *сообщества* к данному *вопросу/ответу*: например, можно поднять тему на *мете* или же спросить в *чате*.

---

P.S.: те *вопросы/ответы*, которые я видел, в которых, как Вы выразились *модераторы* рекомендовали принять ответ, были с неприятными ответами довольно-таки больший срок, чем получение *e-mail* рассылки.

Comment: Если б галочка была призвана указывать на то, что ответ помог конкретному человеку в конкретный промежуток времени, и не несла смысла в долгосрочной перспективе, то в stack exchange не было бы смысла, а использовали бы мейл листы без индексации их поисковиками.

Comment: так как *галочка* может быть установлена только тс, то она как раз таки отражает что данный ответ помог автору вопроса, а количество плюсов как раз таки выражает полезность для *всех*.

Answer (score 5):

Вы забываете существенную деталь.
**Автор обычно задаёт вопрос, потому что не знает на него ответа.**
(Кроме вопросов-автоответов, но таких мало и там мотивация уже сложнее.)

Комментарии вроде:

> Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Не более чем **объясняют суть галочки** и **напоминают о её существовании**. В том, что галочка попала на плохой ответ, виноват исключительно **тот, кто её поставил**. Поставить её может лишь автор вопроса, и его обвинять трудно: он же не знал ответа, и критерии правильности у него вряд ли хорошо выработаны. Он проверяет правильность ответа лишь в своём ограниченном контексте (возможно, **пустом**, особенно если вопрос теоретический).

---

Подобные напоминания не были бы нужны, **если бы все участники сообщества априори знали о назначении галочки** и всегда помнили о её существовании, ведь это часть основной механики StackExchange.

**Хорошо же, когда все знают о правилах и следуют им?**

Давайте на секунду предположим, что бы было, если бы все участники всегда помнили о том, как работает StackExchange, и система работала бы именно так, как была задумана, за вычетом неосведомлённости участников о правилах.

**Галочек на плохих ответах стало бы даже больше.**

---

Так что разбираться с такими случаями придётся постфактум, потому что StackExchange так работает *в идеальных условиях*. Галочки **будут** ставить в неуместные им места.

---

См. также:

- [Что делать, если принятый ответ — ошибочный или вредоносный?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/961/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)
- *(англ.)* [Если захотелось написать ответ, чужая галочка не должна вас останавливать](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299856/2076787)

Comment: На остальном Stack Exchange человеку напоминают о том, что нужно ставить галочку только если у него накопилось много вопросов без них, а не просто для того, чтоб галочки везде были. Хорошего, правильного и вообще рабочего ответа может не найтись на протяжении месяцев, но новичок видит комментарий от модератора и стремится сделать так, чтоб от него смотритель отвязался.

Comment: @Nakilon и это нормально, если новичок счёл принятый ответ "достаточным". Потом переставит галочку, если появится ответ получше. А если проблема не решилась, даже новички имеют обыкновение галочку снимать. Не вижу в этом проблемы.

Comment: Вероятность, что ответ получше появится от выставления галочки падает в разы. Это известный факт.

Comment: @Nakilon "Это известный факт" ничего не означает без подкрепления хотя бы статистикой. Которая тоже не идеальна, но это хоть что-то. Я могу утверждать *обратное* за себя: у меня мотивации опровергнуть **принятый** неправильный ответ (чем-то кроме минуса) заметно больше, чем непринятый. Что-то на грани ощущения "пусть лежит на свалке истории без особых пометок".

Comment: Ну если вы на столько мало знаете Stack Exchange, чтоб не знать таких фактов, то диалога не выйдет.

Comment: @Nakilon если прятаться за *заявленным* опытом, подкреплённым только личным свидетельством, то да, конструктивного диалога не выйдет. Всего хорошего.

Comment: *A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer.* -- это было уже во 2й ревизии из 32 ревизий ответа http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/150545, который является единственным и в тоже время Community wiki. Автором констатации факта является http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/9314/random Так что вы или для себя признаете, что мало знаете Stack Exchange, или в диалоге и правда нет смысла, если один из двух намеренно отрицает известные факты лишь в надежде, что "оппоненту" будет влом привести заведомо существующие доказательства

Comment: А то, что ваше отрицание этого факта уже получило два плюса, не менее, чем в четвертый раз на этой странице *Прекрасно отображает...*

Comment: @Nakilon а я, хе-хе, его и не отрицаю, я потребовал доказательств и привёл контрпример (чтобы стало ясно, для чего доказательства). А ваш тезис из написанного там напрямую не следует. То, что ответ получит меньше внимания, вовсе не означает, что вероятность получить ответ получше упадёт *в разы*, поскольку **просто смотрят** на вопросы одни люди, а **отвечает** в основном активное их подмножество, которое, при активности у нас, обычно успевает просмотреть **все** последние вопросы. Когда сообщество существенно вырастет, это может и будет иметь значение. А пока это совершенно безобидно.

Answer (score 3):

А что мешает вам дать хороший развернутый ответ? Наличие другого ответа? Отметка этого ответа галкой? В вопросе ["Как работает self в Ruby?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548266/) вы поленились дать собственный ответ: перечислить случаи и приемы работы с self в Ruby и продемонстрировать их воспроизводимым кодом (согласен это большая работа и требует времени, меня хватило на один частный случай). Однако не поленились дать комментарий к другому ответу под видом ответа. Это не конструктивно и порождает дискуссию.

Вместо этого, самым лучшим было бы привести свой развернутый ответ на **вопрос** автора или хотя бы рассмотреть еще один частный случай, усилив полезность страницы для тех, кто будет искать ответ на этот вопрос. Посетители, которые придут позже проголосуют за ответ (или несколько), который наиболее лучше всего им подходит. Количество голосов сообщит о том, скольким посетителям помог ответ. Те, кто заинтересован в изучении вопроса изучит все вопросы по теме.

Ответ в стиле, тут все не правильно, а сформулировать правильный ответ у меня нет времени - сильно подрывает авторитет ресурса, а, следовательно, и работу остальных участников.

Comment: Кто сказал, что мне что-то мешает? Про "поленился дать ответ" не правда, потому как ответ был дан абзацем текста на пять строк. И "случай" в этом абзаце приведен. Соответственно третий абзац этого ответа не имеет ничего общего с реальностью.

Answer (score 3):

> на вопрос уже дан один (и только один) ответ, содержащий ошибки, но он уже принят, а потому последующие ответы не получат столько внимания, как первый

Видите ли какое дело: так устроены люди. И вообще все живые существа. Мы несовершенны, нелогичны и абсурдны.

- Первый ответ получает больше внимания и чаще бывает принят.
- Покупатель скорее купит у того продавца, кто активнее рекламирует, а не у того, чей товар лучше.
- Девушка скорее выйдет замуж за того, кто позвал раньше, а не за того, кто гораздо лучше, но не позвал.
- Утята считают мамой тот объект, который был рядом в их первые минуты после вылупления, даже если это не утка.

Не отчаивайтесь, так бывает. Пишите хорошие ответы, они всё равно будут оценены. За галочку репутации дают всего как за полтора голоса, а хорошие ответы нередко набирают десятку и больше. А ещё знак есть специальный - [Популист](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist).

Comment: Продавец -- отвечающий. Покупатель -- вопрошающий. Но зачем вот эти посредники, которые торопят покупателя скорей уходить с рынка и покупать не глядя то, что впарят в самой цветастой упаковке?