# Что делать, если вдруг принимается заведомо неверный ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, тревоги, принятые-ответы

Нет, не [ошибочный или вредоносный](/q/961/178988), а именно заведомо неверный, неработающий и неправильно написанный.

Сейчас столкнулся с тем, что [@ЮрийСветлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199182/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) переставил принятый ответ на [свежезапощенный ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609726/178988). У вопроса есть другие 3 в разной степени работающие варианта, но этот не лезет ни в какие ворота.

1. Код в нём написан неверно. Перед именами классов в css не стоят точки.
   Это  можно было бы исправить правкой (https://jsfiddle.net/b30gpz0v/), но эм..
2. Ширина input'а вообще никак не ограничивается. Он просто вылазит за правую границу и там прячется. 90%, которые просили в вопросе? Нет. Даже не 100.
3. Элемент с `float` имеет нулевую высоту. Тоже можно исправить правкой, но смысл, если сам способ не работает...

Думал поставить тревогу

> **необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством**
>   Ответ имеет серьёзные проблемы с форматированием или контентом. Ответ вряд ли удастся исправить с помощью правок, поэтому его необходимо удалить.

но вспомнил, что

1. Пользователи не могут удалять принятые ответы, значит, вероятно, в лучшем случае ответ отправится модераторам. Насколько модераторы разбираются в html, непонятно.
2. Тревога сама по себе [так себе работает](/q/3259/178988)...

Comment: @PashaPash, что-то ты слишком ключевые слова удаляешь из вопроса. Свежезапощенный ответ вполне может быть хотя бы правдоподобным, а этот - нет.

Comment: мета - не для обсуждения качества конкретных ответов. мне некоторые принятые ответы по C# кажутся бредовыми - но я же молчу.

Comment: А почему не дубликат? Это же _ошибочный ответ_?

Comment: @VladD кстати да

Comment: @Qwertiy фраза "заведомо неверный, неработающий и неправильно написанный" подразумевает что и отвечавший, и поставивший галку заранее знали о "неверности" ответа. очевидно, что это не так.

Comment: @PashaPash, _"мета - не для обсуждения качества конкретных ответов"_ - во-первых, это не так - на metaSO даже специальный тег для этого есть; а во-вторых, я задал вполне общий вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy если убрать слово "заведомо" - то ваш вопрос - умышленный дубликат, созданный ради привлечения минусаторов к конретному ответу. Если слово "заведомо" оставить - то ваш вопрос - попытка привлечь минусаторов на конкретный ответ, обвинив его автора в вандализме.  Выбирайте.

Comment: @Qwertiy ваш вопрос был бы "вполне общим" и не дубликатом, если бы в нем было (1) больше одной ссылки и (2) ссылки вели бы на ответы, где авторы действительно давали бы **заведомо** неверные ответы. Хотите обсуждать проблемы конкретного одного ответа - задавайте конкетный вопрос, без *ключевых* слов "заведомо" и "бредовый", убедившись перед этим, что автор не реагирует на критику в комментариях (это явно не тот случай).

Comment: @PashaPash 1. Обычно и одного примера достаточно, если формулировка более общая. 2. Реагировать он начал после начала обсуждения на мене. 3. Если уж обсуждать конкретный вопрос, то он его довёл до нормального состояния. Но этот метавопрос не об этом же.

Comment: 1. да, но в этом случае пример не соответствует формулировке. из-за "заведомо". 2. а мне вот показалось - что после того, как я ему в комментарии посоветовал перенести предположения о непустоте и ресете из обсуждения в сам ответ. ну и опять же - некоторые отмечают новый год, а не мониторят SO. 3. ну раз не об этом - убирайте несоответствующий (из-за "заведомо") пример из вопроса, ищите другой, где автор назло всем дает неверный ответ, или хотя бы ставит на него галку - и будем обсуждать конкретную проблему. а не теоретическую.

Comment: на самом деле я иногда натыкаюсь на ответы, где автор вопроса поставил галку заведомо зная, что ответ неверен. но пока все такие случаи - по неопытности, из соображений "ну ок, раз не смогли помочь - закрою вопрос. как закрыть? о, поставлю галку". и все решались просто комментарием о том, "как тут принято", после которого галка снималась.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ваш вопрос отличается от [Что делать, если принятый ответ — ошибочный или вредоносный?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/961/) только словами "заведомо неверный". Слово "заведомо" подразумевает, что отвечающий **заранее знал** что ответ неверен, но тем не менее запостил его. По сути вы обвиняете другого участника в вандализме. Если это не так - то я не понимаю, зачем вы создали это обсуждение на мете - оно ведь явный дубликат.

Из комментариев к ответу очевидно, что это не так. Это просто неточный или (возможно!) нерабочий ответ. Но вы настаиваете на на формулировке "**бредовый** и **заведомо** неверный ответ".

Т.е. вы пришли на мету с **заведомо ложными** обвинениями в даче **заведомо** неверного ответа с целью собрать толпу линчевателей-минусаторов против новичка с 50 репутации.

Мы могли бы получить нового отвечателя (пусть и не очень хорошего, не знающего пока что в ответ надо включать возможные оговорки (reset, ширина, непустота, прочее). А получили обиженного новичка, который из-за агрессии минусаторов забьет на SO.

**ВЕДЬ ОН ОШИБСЯ И ЗАСЛУЖИВАЕТ НЕ ТОЛЬКО МИНУСОВ НО И ОТДЕЛЬНОГО ОБСУЖДЕНИЯ НА МЕТЕ! НОВИЧКАМ ТУТ НЕ МЕСТО!**

Нехорошо. Жаль, что минимум 5 человек поддержало травлю.

---

Модераторы не могут быть компетентны во всем.

У модераторов есть даже отдельный пункт для отмены таких тревог:

> не следует использовать сигнал тревоги для неточных или не верных ответов.

И я принципиально выбираю его, даже если моей компетенции хватает, чтобы понять,  что ответ неверен. Я еще могу попробовать удалить ответ, который явно не в тему (например, если кто-то ответит html-ем на вопрос про микроконтроллеры). Но если ответ хоть немного похож на ответ - тревога будет отклонена.

Если считаете, что ответ плохой (не конкретно этот, а вообще любой) - разбирайтесь с ним сами, используя доступные инструменты - минуса.

---

Comment: Позиция абсолютно понятна, чётко обоснована, но не очень хороша. Модераторы - это люди, которые должны заботиться о том, чтобы сайт сделать лучше и краше. Устраняться от схватки - "вы там сами разбирайтесь" - это как-то не очень. Если глубокие причины о которых пишет @Vadim Ovchinnikov невозможно устранить - то хотелось бы чтобы был некоторый институт решения проблем, основанный как на мнении специалистов (трое с золотым знаком по метке) и независимых арбитров (модераторский корпус как подводящий решение).

Comment: @AK вы предлагаете модераторам проводить техническую оценку правильности ответов? т.е. предлагаете мне взять и удалить все ответы по [tag:C#], которые не нравятся лично мне?

Comment: @AK на сайте *есть* " институт решения проблем, основанный как на мнении специалистов" - система минусования. три любых участника могут довести любой ответ до -3, что эффективно предотвратит его использование кем угодно.

Comment: Этот институт не всегда работает. Три _любых_ участника могут как улучшить ситуацию (плохой ответ заминусовать), так и ухудшить (хороший ответ заминусовать). Я же предложил для разбора подобных ситуаций собирать квалифицированную тройку + независимого арбитра (не обязательно разбирающегося в теме, просто имеющего права "подводящего итоги".

Comment: Хм. Давайте так. Оформлю отдельным ответом, чтобы там можно было обсудить.

Comment: @AK я просто не понимаю - зачем? какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить? вы уверены, что пачки минусов и прозрачности ответа недостаточно? собирать консилиум ... для снятия зеленой галки?

Comment: Это решает проблему легитимности, без неё вы не отличите толпу, устроившую суд Линча (особенно, если кто-то тихо воспользуется дополинтельными учётками) от конструктивной и улучшающей пачки минусов под неверным ответом.

Comment: @AK ок, вот вам другая точка зрения на текущую ситуацию - Qwertiy запостил на мете **явный** дубликат, назвав чужой ответ бредовым (!) и **заведомо (!) неверным**. По сути он обвинил двух человек - отвечающего и топикастера - в установке зеленой галки на **заведомо** неправильный ответ. Т.е. он обвинил двух участников в вандализме. Потому что если убрать "заведомо" - то этот вопрос - дубликат, и Qwertiy об этом знал. Т.е. единственный повод создания этого вопроса на мете - собрать толпу Линча для минусования конкретного ответа.

Comment: @AK наверное, стоит перенести это в ответ

Comment: В ответ [уже не получится](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4364/), тут скорее новый вопрос задавать и я не уверен, что хорошо сформулирую вопрос, чтобы действительно указать на проблему. Вы правильно пишете, что текущая система работает, я тоже согласен, что работает (хоть и не всегда). Примеры мои больше гипотетические и пока на практике я не видел, чтобы кто-то собирал ботнет учёток для явно деструктивных действий. Правила -- это весьма краеугольная вещь, как её сбалансируешь - так она и поплывёт. И менять можно, но лучше семь раз отмерить.

Comment: (продолжение предыщего комментария, не влезло) Владимир указывает на весьма глубокие проблемы текущей модели, но не факт, что при устранении этих проблем мы не получим другие, ещё худшие. Давайте я пока ограничусь вот каким замечанием и не буду пока новый вопрос писать. Есть проблема того, что голоса всех участников равноправны: неважно, что у тебя золото по знаку -- но тебе приходится прибегать к умножающему коэффициенту (уговаривая в чате/мете других участников усилить воздействие). Насколько это большая проблема и проблема ли вообще -- надо ещё подумать.

Comment: Для тех, кто будет читать это не по горячим следам: ветка комментариев выше этого относилась к предыдущей версии ответа - той, что сейчас после отчёркнутой линии.

Comment: @AK перенес в свой ответ. я не хочу в рамках этого вопроса обсуждать "что делать с неверным ответами" - для этого есть существующий вопрос. Но идея консилиума или неравенства голосов мне не нравится.

Comment: Принято. Давайте подождём, пока не появится другой прецедент, в котором более выпукло проявятся затронутые вопросы, а не проявится -- значит, будем считать, что текущая система вполне хорошо с этим работает.

Comment: @PashaPash Я вам, честно скажу, что Qwertiy тут прав, был выбран ответ, которые не запускается и из сниппета было видно, что он нерабочий и совсем не подходит как ответ, даже сейчас с учётом правок он с большой натяжкой подходит.

Comment: @PashaPash Чисто моё мнение. Если бы этот человек был бы забанен было бы неплохо, потому что он, я уверен, продолжит оскорблять участников и он, как я заметил, не сильно охотно поддерживает конструктивный разговор.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov будет оскорблять - забанят, всего делов. рабочий/не рабочий - не мне решать (этому собственно у меня половина ответа посвящена)

Comment: *Жаль, что минимум 5 человек поддержало травлю.* |¦| *разбирайтесь с ним сами, используя доступные инструменты - минуса.* |¦| Момент, то есть, мы следуем вашим рекомендациям и при этом жаль, что мы так делаем? На тот момент минусов ответ очень даже заслуживал и было ясно сказано, почему. И лично я, из этих пяти минусаторов, считаю шквал минусов вполне заслуженным, чем бы ни было привлечено внимание. И на минусы поступила конструктивная реакция: правка, выправляющая очевидные проблемы. Система уже сработала в интересах сообщества, хотя бы частично. (в один комментарий не помещается)

Comment: ...и теперь нужна реакция на новую редакцию ответа. Она тоже поступила. Мета умножила эффект, ярче показав, как работает сообщество. Не вижу оснований о чём-либо тут жалеть, система так работает. Просто статистически поведение видно тем точнее, чем с большего числа действий оно изучается.

Comment: @D-side получения конструктивной реакции достаточно минуса + комментария. поток молчаливых минусов с меты - это слишком. такие минусующие не оставляют комментариев, и не следят за внесением правок в ответ.  пост был исправлен - но минуса на нем остались висеть до тех пор, пока я не отредактировал вопрос на мете.

Comment: @PashaPash а что эти минусующие должны были сказать? Повторить уже сказанное? А смысл? Да, по-хорошему, минусаторам надо пересматривать актуальность своих минусов после правок. И должен заметить, что даже в случае с ответами SO слабо к таким действиям подталкивает (желание отменить - 1 у своей репутации), а в случае с вопросами совсем не подталкивает, даже понимающие и желающие не имеют для этого инструментов на сайте. Это проблема.

Comment: Тоже пожалуй добавлю реакцию на значительно изменившийся ответ, особенно с учётом что я [процитировал его](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4382/213987) в другом вопросе. Я тоже там был, среди минусоваших, а потом снявших минус после правки. На репутацию я не вёлся, прочитал внимательно комменатрии, составил своё мнение, решил, что жалеть минус не стоит - поставил, взял этот вопрос под присмотр. Когда ответ был доведён до ума -- снял минус. То, что мета и чаты выступают мультипликаторами -- это всем известный момент, крамолы в этом нет.

Comment: @D-side к моменту основных минусов под ответом уже были уточняющие комментарии от автора. Минусаторам надо было написать "перенесите свои пояснения в ответ" :)

Answer (score 12):

Что делать?
Яростно минусить неверный ответ. Случайно наткнувшийся на вопрос юзер врядли рискнет воспользоваться ответом со множеством минусов.

Почему удалять ответ, снимать галку etc - нельзя?
Потому что галка - это не признак "ответ верный". Это признак "ответ помог топикстартеру".
А помочь можно по разному: можно дать готовое решение, можно навести на реальное решение (даже случайно). А может тс прочитал ответ, решил бросить программирование и работать на ферме - тоже помощь.

Если есть подозрение, что юзер таким образом себе репутацию накручивает с разных аккаунтов, то проверять это - дело модераторов, и обрабатываться это должно существующими механизмами работы с мультиакками.

Comment: Ответ не мог помочь. Он ну вот вообще никак к этому вопросу...

Comment: А яростных минусаторов пока не видно. Там всего лишь 2 минуса, да ещё и 1 плюс (возможно, вместе с принятием).

Comment: `прочитал ответ, решил бросить программирование и работать на ферме` – я бы хотел научиться писать ответы с такой степенью вразумления. )

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, что здесь есть несколько древних проблем, которые лежат очень глубоко. Перечисляю их по приоритетам

1. При сортировке ответов принятый ответ всегда сверху. Если бы не это, не было бы борьбы за принятый ответ и кучи комментариев "*This should be accepted answer*". И даже [многочисленные мольбы это поменять](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) успешно игнорируются, объясняя это чуть ли не главной фишкой сайта. Принятый ответ — главный фетиш этого сайта. И это несправедливо, потому что это только в определённой мере делать виденье одного человека (даже если он спросил) главным. Если честно: ну кому какая разница что подошло одному человеку? Пусть принятый ответ пусть стоит, но где-то глубоко внизу для некоторых случаев. В топе, по хорошему, должно же быть самое полезное для всех...
2. Вытекает из первой. Даже если бы [убрали сверху глубоко заминусованные](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255706/why-are-negative-score-accepted-answers-still-at-the-top) ответы, то было бы легче, и этот ответ был бы далеко внизу и способ ставить минусы более явно бы помогал.
3. Нет никакой встроенной возможности отмечать тревогой ответ как содержащий ложные сведения. Да, можно звать модераторов и надеятся на их компетенцию и желание удалять и т.д. Да, ещё можно голосать против. Но это всё выглядит как обходной путь (workaround), а не решение самой проблемы. И далеко не всегда поможет.
4. Неадекватность вопрошающего, нежелание что-то менять или просто когда автор вопроса покинул сайт. Тут уже всё сложно. Ничего толком не поделаешь с тем, что автору понравилось что-то низкосортное. Минусовать вопрос — неконструктивно, потому что вопрос, может, очень даже толков. А что тут ещё можно сделать?
5. Ну и наконец неадекватность отвечающего, нежелание что-то менять или просто когда автор ответа покинул сайт. Тут уже всё сложно. Можно минусовать, и чаще всего, только так.

---

Как видно из представленными мною причинами неадекватность отвечающего на последнем месте. Поэтому, как мне кажется, всё-таки следует думать, что можно поменять на главных причинах, и затем менее приоритетные либо разрешаться, либо будут некритичны.

Comment: Я понимаю, что можно принять некачественный ответ по принципу "шмякнул хак за 5 минут и на вид всё работает" - да, тут комментарии о том, что не так с ответом, как раз в тему. И удалять не нужно, чтобы люди видели, что такое возможно, но так делать не надо. Но когда ответ вообще не подходит к вопросу, то эм...

Comment: @Qwertiy Да я согласен, но такие ответы "шмякнул хак за 5 минут и на вид всё работает" не должны быть в топе. И бывают ответы, в которых содержатся именно ложные сведения. Я этот пример не имел ввиду.

Answer (score 4):

Тревога "необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством" категорически не подходит для этой ситуации. Она для ситуаций, когда вместо ответа опубликован невменяемый абырвалг.

Вообще странно видеть теоретические рассуждения о коде из связки html+css(+js). Специально для вас и только для этой связки на сайте есть сниппеты. Всё же просто: нажимаем синюю кнопку, если видим желаемый результат — ответ, возможно, хороший. Если не видно желаемого результата — ответ, наверняка, плохой.

Comment: Я в комментарии там ссылку на jsfiddle добавил. Потому что посчитал правку, делающую нерабочий сниппет несколько странной и бессмысленной.

Comment: @Qwertiy сниппет делает нерабочесть кода явной, думаю что это хорошо. Явно нерабочий код сложно называть лучшим и гениальным.