# Правка чужого принятого ответа с логической ошибкой

Tags: поддержка, правки

Хотелось бы уточнить, стоит ли править принятый ответ, если там есть ошибка (в логике кода), а точнее эта ошибка сохранена из кода в вопросе и ей не уделено никакое внимание?
Например, [задается вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676184/218779):

> ```
> public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
>     for (Object a : array) {
>         a.equals(obj) ? return true : return false;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Как работает тернарный оператор в java? что не так с кондицией?

Дается [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676189/218779):

> Во-первых, можно проще:
>
> ```
> public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
>     for (Object a : array) {
>         return a.equals(obj);
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```
>
> Во-вторых, если же Вам уж очень хочется использовать тернарный
>   оператор, то синтаксис у Вас хромает, и нужно так:
>
> ```
> public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
>     for (Object a : array) {
>         return a.equals(obj) ? true : false;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```
>
> PS. Оба метода возвращают false, если array пустой.
>
> PPS. Логику метода во внимание не принимал (а она не верна), поправил
>   только тернарный оператор.

Сразу видно, что у автора вопроса ошибка. Если первый элемент массива не эквивалентен `obj`, мы получим `false` и вернемся из метода. Не логично ли указать это в ответе, хоть и вопрос заключается в другом?

Comment: Вот немного по смежной тематике: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/961/10105

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я считаю, что автор будучи адекватным, должен понять её и не сбивать с толку других участников, которые могут прийти и увидеть данный ответ. Автор банально  может его (ответ) исправить, удалив неверную информацию.

В данном случае автору сразу об этом сообщили в комментарии.
К сожалению, вместо исправления этого появилась всего лишь приписка в стиле "на вот это и отвали". Это я про **PPS**.

Моё мнение — такой ответ не является верным и я голосую против. На вопрос, кстати, ответа и не было. Ведь вопрос звучал:

> Как работает тернарный оператор в java?

Так что ответ вдвойне неверный.

Как можно поступать другим участникам сообщества с подобными ответами описано в смежной теме [Что делать, если принятый ответ — ошибочный или вредоносный?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/961/191482)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не надо. Во-первых, вопорс не об этом, во-вторых, автор ответа и так об этом написал. Если есть желание, можно написать свой ответ.

Comment: Автор ответа об этом написал после моего комментария. Что кстати говорил о том, что изначально он был еще более неправильным) Но разве не логично исправить ответ, а не подписывать доп. фразы лишь бы отвалили?